# Как запустить анимацию в json модели с помощью программы three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

У меня есть вот такой код который запускает анимацию на страничке

```
new THREE.ObjectLoader().load( url, function ( loadedObject ) {
loadedObject.traverse( function ( child ) {
if ( child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh ) {
mesh = child;
}  
} );

scene.add( mesh );
skeleton = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( mesh );
skeleton.visible = false;
scene.add( skeleton );

mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );

idleAction = mixer.clipAction( 'idle' );
walkAction = mixer.clipAction( 'walk' );
runAction = mixer.clipAction( 'run' );
actions = [ idleAction, walkAction, runAction ];

actions.forEach( function ( action ) {action.play();} );

json()

});


function animated() {
    var mixerUpdateDelta = clock.getDelta();
            mixer.update( mixerUpdateDelta );
    }   



function json(){    
requestAnimationFrame( json_end_scene );    
animated()
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Но есть небольшая проблема в том что для нормального вывода необходимо знать точное название действия. Что крайне неудобно

```
  idleAction = mixer.clipAction( 'idle' );
```

я пытался вставить как в большинстве примеров

```
  var action = mixer.clipAction( child.animations[0] )
```

Я так и не понял за что необходимо зацепить ".animations[0]" что бы он работал нормально есть ли у кого идеи как это сделать?

Comment: я бы полез глянуть, но без модели некуда..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я использовал обычную модель из примера marine_anims_core.json

Comment: какого примера?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ webgl_animation_skinning_blending.html только особенность в том что есть 2 разные версий первая https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_blending но там используется gltf и вторая которая находится в папке examples в архиве three.js-master который скачивается на официальном сайте. Я использовал второй вариант. Я не знаю почему на сайте и в архиве они отличаются.